# Ceiling and Floor Function Properties

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

When solving a problem I came across the expression $⌈n⌉+⌊m⌋$, where n and m are real numbers.

Given that we know:
$n≤⌈n⌉<n+1$ and $m-1<⌊m⌋≤m$, I was wondering if any conclusions can be drawn about the inequality that satisfies the expression $⌈n⌉+⌊m⌋$.

By plugging in numbers is appears that $n+m<⌈n⌉+⌊m⌋≤n+m+1$, but I'm not sure if this is correct or how to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $⌈n⌉<n+1$ and $⌊m⌋\leq m$ we have $$⌈n⌉+⌊m⌋<n+1+m$$

and since $n\leq ⌈n⌉$ and $m-1<⌊m⌋$ we have $$n+m-1<⌈n⌉+⌊m⌋$$

so we have $$\boxed{n+m-1<⌈n⌉+⌊m⌋<n+m+1}$$

Comment: Thanks. I now understand how to do this, but when I applied the same logic on finding the corresponding inequality for $⌈⌉-⌈m⌉$ I got $n-m≤⌈n⌉-⌈m⌉<n-m$. This result is clearly wrong and I was wondering as to why?